# Multiple date formats in MSSQL varchar column

Tags: sql-server, datetime, date-format

I have the following date formats in MSSQL varchar field :

```
12/31/2011 4:15:22 PM +0500
31/12/2011 4:15:22 PM +0500
2013-08-17 1:59:19 PM +0500
Aug 26 2013  2:49PM
```

Can anyone suggest me a function which will convert all these fomarts into one datetime format.

i am unable to change this table as this solutions is deployed more than 100 places.

awaiting for a solution.

Comment: You should never store date values in a `varchar` field.  Use `datetime`, `datetime2` or `datetimeoffset` as appropriate.

Answer (score 3):

You can find many post about how to convert given a format, and a varchar field.

I don't think there is a way to convert all varchar value to a date, because it is an ambiguous request..

**Given this value:
02/03/2011 4:15:22 PM +0500**

How will i know if it's 2 of March or 3 of February?

If you you are looking for explanation about how to do this given format:
http://www.sql-server-helper.com/sql-server-2008/sql-server-2008-date-format.aspx